# XGBoost custom objective/loss: when is a Reverse (inverse) Link Function required?

Tags: boosting, loss-functions, gradient-descent, link-function

I'm trying to implement a custom objective function in XGBoost. I read [the docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html) on this topic. I am not sure if I need to define a "reverse link function" (aka inverse link function) to properly implement my custom objective, and the documentation is pretty difficult to decypher.

In my objective, the raw output of the regression model is $f(x_i) = f_i = log(\sigma_i)$, the logarithm of the estimated (conditional) standard deviation. The loss is the negative log-likelihood of the targets under the assumption that each target $y_i$ comes from a normal distribution with zero mean and standard deviation $\sigma_i$. The loss, gradient, and hessian are (ignoring constant $c$):
$$
loss(y,f) = c +\sum_if_i+\frac{y_i^2}{2e^{2f_i}} $$
$$
grad_i(y_i, f_i) = 1-y_i^2/e^{2f_i}
$$
$$
hess_i(y_i,f_i) = 2y_i^2/e^{2f_i}
$$
Again, I'm not sure if XGBoost requires me to also define a reverse link function. I suppose my link function would be $\sigma_i= e^{f_i}$. I am fine working with the untransformed $f_i$ but I'm not sure if XGboost is.